# Is a function that calls Math.random() pure?

Tags: javascript, function, pure-function

Is the following a pure function?

```
function test(min,max) {
   return  Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

My understanding is that a pure function follows these conditions:

1. It returns a value computed from the parameters
2. It doesn't do any work other than calculating the return value

If this definition is correct, is my function a pure function? Or is my understanding of what defines a pure function incorrect?

Comment: "It doesn't do any work other than calculating the return value" But it calls `Math.random()` which changes the state of the RNG.

Comment: The second point is more like "it does not changes external (to the function) state"; and the first should be complemented somewhat like "it returns the SAME value computed from the SAME parameters", as people have writen below

Comment: Is there a notion of a semipure function, allowing for randomness? E.g. `test(a,b)` always returns the same object `Random(a,b)` (which can represent different concrete numbers)? If you keep `Random` symbolic it is pure in the classical sense, if you evaluate it early and put in numbers, maybe as a kind of optimization, the function still retains some "pureness".

Comment: "Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." - John von Neumann

Comment: @jdm if it returns the same Random object, as opposed to a random number, then it is pure

Comment: @jdm if you follow the thread of "semi-pure", where you consider functions pure modulo some *well-defined* side-effects, you might end up inventing monads.  Welcome to the dark side. >:)

Comment: @immibis We would need an immutable Random object that would return a tuple (NewRandom, randomNumber), which we'd then have to return from this function to make it useful. Seems doable if rather weird.

Comment: @Voo In that case it's pure, but the purity is not very useful because you have to pass a different Random object every time.

Comment: @immibis It's certainly awkward to use in Javascript, but you could use it just as the non-pure function just by passing state around (which is how functional programming works in general).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244023/is-date-now-referential-transparent .

Answer (score 194, accepted):

No, it's not. Given the same input, this function will return different values. And then you can't build a 'table' that maps the input and the outputs.

From the Wikipedia article for [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> The function always evaluates the same result value given the same
>   argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any
>   hidden information or state that may change while program execution
>   proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it
>   depend on any external input from I/O devices

Also, another thing is that a pure function can be replaced with a table which represents the mapping from the input and output, as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766448/replacing-functions-with-table-lookups).

If you want to rewrite this function and change it to a pure function, you should pass the random value as an argument too

```
function test(random, min, max) {
   return random * (max - min) + min;
}
```

and then call it this way (example, with 2 and 5 as min and max):

```
test( Math.random(), 2, 5)
```

Comment: What if you were to re-seed the random generator each time inside the function before calling `Math.random`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Even then, it would still have side-effects (changing future `Math.random` output); for it to be pure, you'd have to somehow save the current RNG state, reseed it, call `Math.random`, and restore it to the previous state.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ All computed RNG is based around faking randomness. Something has to be running underneath that causes it to appear random and you can't account for that, making it impure. Also, and probably more important to your question, you can't seed Math.random

Comment: @LegionMammal978 …and do so atomically.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: You might consider accepting an instance of `lang.util.Random`, though the state of that would of course get changed, making it impure, but allowing the caller to control what gets affected. Also as far as I can see `lang.util.Random` is Java but not JavaScript.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: ... or an instance of `util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom` or `util/security/SecureRandom` (which are actually subclasses).

Comment: Another way to make pure function from a function that uses an RNG is to pass in the RNG state into and out of the function: `function test(rng, min, max) { [rng, rand] = next(rng); return [rng, rand * (max - min) + min]; }`

Comment: @PJTraill there is no `lang.util.Random` in java either. Maybe you meant `java.util.Random`? Also, as this question is about javascript, not java, they are anyway unrelated here.

Comment: @eis: Thanks, of course I meant `java.util.Random`. I thought it worth mentioning as you could presumably do or use something similar in JavaScript.

Comment: @LieRyan: As I read the Wikipedia definition of _pure_, changing the state of a passed argument is also not allowed.

Comment: @PJTrail: where did you see my version of the function change the state of passed argument?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ There are ways to have RNGs that do operate with pure functions, but it involves passing the RNG state to the function and having the function return the replacement RNG state, which is how Haskell (a functional programming language that enforces functional purity) achieves it.

Comment: @LieRyan: I was thinking that `next(rng)` would change the state of `rng`, but I confess I do not know what `next` does – is this a library function (which I could not find) or your own, and what is / where can I find its specification?

Comment: @PJTraill: `next()` is any function, that is part of the RNG, which, given the RNG state `rng`, returns a tuple containing the next RNG state `rng'` and the next random number in the RNG. In the code `[rng1, a] = next(rng); [rng2, b] = next(rng)`, it will always be the case that `rng1 == rng2` and `a == b`. To get the next number in the PRNG, you would be required to do: `[rng1, a] = next(rng); [rng2, b] = next(rng1)`. In functional languages like Haskell though, you'll likely be using monad here to avoid having to explicitly pass rng state around everywhere.

Comment: @PJTraill: note that RNG does not necessarily need to be a pseudo RNG for next() and test() to remain pure with above implementation, it could be a true (hardware) RNG, and you'd handle it the same way you do IO in pure languages.

Answer (score 53):

The simple answer to your question is that **`Math.random()` violates rule #2.**

Many other answers here have pointed out that the presence of `Math.random()` means that this function is not pure. But I think it's worth saying *why* `Math.random()` taints functions that use it.

Like all pseudorandom number generators, `Math.random()` starts with a "seed" value. It then uses that value as the starting point for a chain of low-level bit manipulations or other operations that result in an unpredictable (but not really *random*) output.

In JavaScript, the process involved is implementation-dependent, and unlike many other languages, JavaScript provides [no way to select the seed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

That's why this function isn't pure: JavaScript is essentially using an implicit function parameter that you have no control over. It's reading that parameter from data calculated and stored elsewhere, and therefore violates rule #2 in your definition.

If you wanted to make this a pure function, you could use one of the alternative random number generators described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript). Call that generator `seedable_random`. It takes one parameter (the seed) and returns a "random" number. Of course, this number isn't really random at all; it is uniquely determined by the seed. That's why this is a pure function. The output of `seedable_random` is only "random" in the sense that predicting the output based on the input is difficult.

The pure version of this function would need to take *three* parameters:

```
function test(min, max, seed) {
   return  seedable_random(seed) * (max - min) + min;
}
```

For any given triple of `(min, max, seed)` parameters, this will always return the same result.

Note that if you wanted the output of `seedable_random` to be *truly* random, you'd need to find a way to randomize the seed! And whatever strategy you used would inevitably be non-pure, because it would require you to gather information from a source outside your function. As [mtraceur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035166/is-a-function-that-calls-math-random-pure/47037297?noredirect=1#comment81070224_47037297) and [jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035166/is-a-function-that-calls-math-random-pure/47037297?noredirect=1#comment81075739_47037297) remind me, this includes all physical approaches: [hardware random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator), [webcams with lens caps](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/webcam-random-number-generator), [atmospheric noise collectors](https://www.random.org/) -- even [lava lamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavarand). All of these involve using data calculated and stored outside the function.

Comment: Math.random() not only reads its "seed" but also modifies it, so that the next call will return something different.  Depending on, and modifying, static state is definitely bad for a pure function.

Comment: @NateEldredge, quite so! Though simply reading an implementation-dependent value is enough to break purity. For example, ever notice how Python 3 hashes aren't stable between processes?

Comment: How would this answer change if `Math.random` did not use a PRNG but was instead implemented using a hardware RNG? The hardware RNG doesn't really have state in the normal sense, but it does produce random values (and thus function output is still different regardless of input), right?

Comment: @mtraceur, that's correct. But I don't think the answer would change much. In fact, this is why I don't spend time talking about "state" in my answer. Reading from a hardware RNG also means reading from "data calculated and stored elsewhere." It's just that the data is calculated and stored in the physical medium of the computer itself as it interacts with its environment.

Comment: @mtraceur, thinking a bit more, I see that although I still think my answer wouldn't change, the definition of "doing work" in rule #2 above would have to be specified carefully in the case of a hardware RNG. Perhaps "it doesn't do any work" should really be "it doesn't depend on any work done."

Comment: @mtraceur, Or there might be a QM-based argument: when we read a random value, we cause a change in the state of the world through the mechanisms of [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence). The state change is the work done.

Comment: Predicting the output based on the input is not difficult at all (after all, there is some code which implements just that).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, I can see how "predicting" isn't exactly right. But that is often how hash functions are described, and what you say is true of them too, isn't it?

Comment: This same logic applies even to more sophisticated randomization schemes, even ones like [Random.org's atmospheric noise](https://www.random.org). +1

Comment: @NateEldredge The RNG algorithm is unspecified and the RNG cannot be reseeded, so there is _no way to observe_ whether a `Math.random` call has actually happened. Therefore, calling `Math.random` and discarding the result is OK in a pure function. You cannot tell the presence or lack of such a call to `Math.random` apart by replacing the call to this pure function with its return value, because when doing so, you need a new execution, which has a new seed.

Answer (score 40):

A pure function is a function where the return value is only determined by its input values, without observable side effects

By using Math.random, you are determining its value by something other than input values. It's not a pure function.

[source](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/)

Answer (score 25):

No, it isn't a pure function because its output doesn't depend *only* on the input provided (Math.random() can output any value), while pure functions should always output the same value for same inputs.

If a function is pure, it's safe to optimize away multiple calls with the same inputs and just reuse the result of an earlier call.

P.S for me at least and for many others, redux made the term ***pure function*** popular. [Straight from the redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions):

> Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - ***Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().***

Comment: Although others have provided great answers, but i couldn't resist myself when redux doc's came to my mind and Math.random() specifically mentioned in them :)

Answer (score 21):

From mathematical point of view, your signature is not

```
test: <number, number> -> <number>
```

but

```
test: <environment, number, number> -> <environment, number>
```

where the `environment` is capable of providing results of `Math.random()`.
And actually generating the random value mutates the environment as a side effect, so you also return a new environment, which is not equal to the first one!

In other words, if you need any kind of input that does not come from initial arguments (the `<number, number>` part), then you need to be provided with execution environment (that in this example provides state for `Math`). The same applies to other things mentioned by other answers, like I/O or such.

---

As an analogy, you can also notice this is how object-oriented programming can be represented - if we say, e.g.

```
SomeClass something
T result = something.foo(x, y)
```

then actually we are using

```
foo: <something: SomeClass, x: Object, y: Object> -> <SomeClass, T>
```

with the object that has its method invoked being part of the environment. And why the `SomeClass` part of result? Because `something`'s state could have changed as well!

Comment: Worse yet, the environment is also mutated, so `test: <environment, number, number> -> <environment, number>` it should be

Comment: I'm not sure the OO example is very similar. `a.F(b, c)` can be seen as syntactic sugar for `F(a, b, c)` with a special rule to despatch to overloaded definitions of `F` based on the type of `a` (this is actually how Python represents it). But `a` is still explicit in both notations, whereas the environment in a non-pure function is never mentioned in the source code.

Answer (score 11):

Pure functions always return the same value for same input.
Pure functions are predictable and are referential transparent which means that we can replace the function call with the output returned and it will not change the working of the program.

https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide/blob/master/ch3.md

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers that correctly point out how this function is non-deterministic, it also has a side-effect: it will cause future calls to `math.random()` to return a different answer.  And a random-number generator that doesn’t have that property will generally perform some kind of I/O, such as to read from a random device provided by the OS. Either is verboten for a pure function.

Answer (score 7):

No, it isn't. You can't figure out the result at all, so this piece of code can't be tested. To make that code testable, you need to extract the component that generates the random number:

```
function test(min, max, generator) {
  return  generator() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Now, you can mock the generator and test your code properly:

```
const result = test(1, 2, () => 3);
result == 4 //always true
```

And in your "production" code:

```
const result = test(1, 2, Math.random);
```

Comment: ▲ for your thought for testability. With a little care you can also produce repeatable tests while accepting a `util.Random`, which you can seed at the start of a test run to repeat old behaviour or for a new (but repeatable) run. If multi-threading, you may be able to do this in the main thread and use that `Random` to seed repeatable thread-local `Random`s. However, as I understand it, `test(int,int,Random)` is not considered pure as it alters the state of the `Random`.

Answer (score 2):

Would you be fine with the following:

```
return ("" + test(0,1)) + test(0,1);
```

be equivalent to

```
var temp = test(0, 1);
return ("" + temp) + temp;
```

?

You see, the definition of pure is a function whose output does not change with anything other than its inputs. If we say that JavaScript had a way to tag a function pure and take advantage of this, the optimizer would be allowed to rewrite the first expression as the second.

I have practical experience with this. SQL server allowed `getdate()` and `newid()` in "pure" functions and the optimizer would dedupe calls at will. Sometimes this would do something dumb.